# problem when i run my project with php artisan ser In RouteFileRegistrar.php line 35:

Tags: php, server, laravel-artisan

In RouteFileRegistrar.php line 35:

require(C:\wamp64\www\routes/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory! You have to include ``api.php`` in your ``RouteFileRegistrar.php`` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into your path. / \ are mixed. I guess Windows is having some issues with it.

Comment: thanks for reply >>but all projects is working else this project>>?

Comment: Please post the include of your api.php in RouteFileRegistrar.php.
Compare that one to your "other projects".

Comment: thanks for reply >>put i change IDE PHPSTORM  WITH VISUAL STUDIO CODE WORKING >>>, but  where  is the proplem??  . I don't know

Answer (score 0):

First, try running the following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, proceed to the second step:

```
rm -rf {_ROOT_}/storage/framework/cache/data/*
```

This error appears to be related to a caching issue, where the path to the cache files is incorrect. You should check the permissions of the framework cache directory.

In my case, the issue arose during the automated deployment process on GitHub Actions with the Laravel Modules package, where cache files created on the build server were inadvertently pushed to the production environment, leading to problems.